# have a variable available in all Yii views

Tags: php, inheritance, yii, scope

I would like to have a variable $user_profile available in most of my view files, without me having to create the variable in each controller file. At the moment I have things working but I was wondering if there is a better solution

I have some code to populate a variable

```
$user_profile = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;
```

Then a parent class

```
class Controller extends CController { 

    public function getUserProfile()
    {
      $user_profile = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;
    }

}
```

Then I have all other controllers inheriting the Controller class, for example

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

public function actionIndex()
{
    $user_profile = parent::getUserProfile();
    $this->render('index', array('user_profile' => $user_profile));

}

}
```

Then finally in the view file I can simply access the $user_profile variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create class field in your base controller class:

```
class Controller extends CController { 
    public $user_profile;

    public function init()
    {
      parent::init();
      $this->user_profile = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;
    }
}
```

Don't need to pass it directly to view:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');
}
```

Then you can access it in view using `$this`:

```
// index.php
var_dump($this->user_profile);
```

Comment: the variable dump returns a null variable
the public variable  public $user_profile; does not reference the getUserProfile method. How should I make this variable reference the method?

Comment: Sorry forgot that you should set `$this->user_profile` in `init` method to have it always initialized, I updated answer.

Comment: all working :) I was just wondering if you could explain the need for parent::init(); I have tried without it and it still works fine

Comment: It is not required in this case, just a habit, because when extending other classses it might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a getter defined, so you can use `$this->userProfile` from both, your controllers and your views. I'd only add a caching logic to avoid multiple queries to the database:

```
class Controller extends CController
{

    protected $_userProfile=false;

    /*
     * @return mixed a User object or null if user not found or guest user
     */
    public function getUserProfile()
    {
        if($this->_userProfile===false) {
            $user = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
            $this->_userProfile = $user===null ? null : $user->profile;
        }
        return $this->_userProfile;
    }
```

Comment: nice solutions and it works fine, but I wonder what is the advantage of using this getter method vs PeterM's solution of just using the init() method

Comment: I think the best advantage of this method is that `userProfile` is readonly - you cant ovveride it in view - because there are no `setUserProfile` method.

Comment: Right, that's the main idea. Getters are one of the secret powers of Yii that many developers hardly ever use. You should get used to them. I actually use constructs above a lot and they help to keep my code very clean.

Answer (score 0):

For user profile info, I populate a small number of variables upon login using setState to store the data.

In your UserIdentity class after a successful authentication, you can store data similar to this:

```
$userRecord = User::model()->find("user_name='".$this->username."'");  
$this->setState('display_name', 
    (isset($userRecord->first_name)) ? 
        $userRecord->first_name : $userRecord->user_name);
```

Then in any view, it can be accessed like:

```
echo (isset(Yii::app()->user->display_name) ? 
        Yii::app()->user->display_name : 'Guest');
```